# How can I query images from a specified folder without uploading them to a database? (SQL)

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I don't know if this is even possible, but I would like to be able to pull images from a file location on my server. Is there a way to accomplish this? Or, would it be best to insert them into my database, and *then* retrieve them?

Comment: Try saving details into xml or json files and then loop through.

Comment: Can you share the image files as SMB or WebDAV?  In which case you could only store the URL to access it.

Comment: @Stavr00 I never thought about using SMB, that would be interesting. I just don't know how I would incorporate that, to be honest. If this is the alternative, I'd rather store the picture files in the database and retrieve them that way.

Comment: @Stavr00  I just see performance being an issue, and Im strapped as is.